# frequency plot for binary variable

Tags: r, binary, boxplot

I am trying to create a simple boxplot for binary variable. I am working with this data:

```
structure(list(status = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), length = c(1520L, 
1250L, 870L, 720L, 820L, 770L, 50L, 570L, 580L, 480L, 470L, 450L, 
435L, 275L, 256L, 230L, 330L, 330L, 300L, 180L), mass = c(9600, 
5000, 3360, 2517, 3170, 4390, 1930, 1020, 910, 590, 539, 940, 
684, 230, 162, 170, 501, 439, 386, 95), range = c(1.21, 0.56, 
0.07, 1.1, 3.45, 2.96, 0.01, 9.01, 7.9, 4.33, 1.04, 2.17, 4.81, 
0.31, 0.24, 0.77, 2.23, 0.22, 2.4, 0.69), migr = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L), insect = c(12L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 12L), diet = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L)), .Names = c("status", "length", "mass", "range", "migr", 
"insect", "diet"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 22L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I have utried using the boxplot function, but only get one box instead of 2.

```
boxplot(birds$status)
```

I also tried the ggplot function:

```
ggplot(birds$status) + geom_boxplot()
ggplot() + aes(birds) + geom_boxplot()
ggplot(birds, aes(x= status, group=status)) + geom_boxplot()
```

How can I obtain a boxplot with two boxes, 0=absence and 1=presence?

Comment: what variable are you trying to plot? The way I understand it is that you wanted to make 2 boxplots (for 0 and 1 categories), but which variable are you interested to see the distribution of?

Comment: Boxplots are for visualizing the spread of continuous variables (possibly grouped by discrete ones), e.g. `ggplot(birds, aes(x = factor(diet), y = mass, fill = factor(status))) + geom_boxplot()`

Comment: @din i a trying to see the counts of how many absences (0) and presences (1)  I have in the variable status. I would like to see the distribution of status variable.

Comment: as @alistaire mentioned, boxplot is for visualizing the spread of continuous variable, it will not be informative with binary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments above, what you are looking for is `barplot` and `table` which calculates the frequency:

```
barplot(table(birds$status))
```

[image]

Comment: @P Lapointe. Thanks, thats what i needed. I will edit the question, to clear up confusion. How can i change the labels on the x-axis?

Comment: @Danka Like this: `barplot(table(birds$status),names.arg = c("Absent","Present"))`             Type this in console `?barplot` for a list of options.